# Static model instances in SQLALchemy with Flask (fixtures)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, fixtures

I am developing a Flask application using SQLAlchemy. For authorization I am using user roles which are a simple SQLAlchemy model with a m2m relation to users. I want that some roles, e.g. 'admin' are automatically created on application startup in case they do not already exist. This is similar to fixtures for unit testing, just without the testing part.

I have tried putting the required code into a function that is registered with the `before_app_first_request` decorator, however I need to push an application context for that to work. The app is not accessible to me in the relevant code, as it is part of an isolated blueprint.

The code would look similar to this:

```
from app import db
my_blueprint = flask.Blueprint(...)
from .models import Role


@my_blueprint.before_app_first_request
def load_fixtures():
    admin_role = Role.query.filter_by(name='admin').first()
    if coach_role is None:
        db.session.add(Role(name='admin'))
        db.session.commit()
```

Is there a preferred way to do this? I.e. run fixtures upon application startup?